# How to handle for promise inside a piped map

Tags: javascript, rxjs, google-cloud-firestore, observable

I am definitely sure I am confused here so please any help is appreciated.

Here is my scenario:

I pull from Firestore a document:

```
return this.afs.collection("events").doc(eventID).snapshotChanges().pipe(
      map( document => {

      })
    );
```

All is fine up to here.

But inside the map I need a promise to resolve (or not)

For example:

```
return this.afs.collection("events").doc(eventID).snapshotChanges().pipe(
      map( document => {
        // This is a promise the below part 
        const data = await EventImporterJSON.getFromJSON(document.payload.data())
        return data
      })
    );
```

I understand that the `await` cannot happen there. I am very confused how to solve this, perhaps I have not worked long enough with observables and rxjs.

In the end what I am trying to achieve is:

Get the document. Map and process it but inside the process, I need to handle a promise.

I don't want to return that promise to the caller though.

Does this make sense?

Or have I structured this completely wrong?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

This is a typical use-case for `mergeMap` or `concatMap`:

```js
return this.afs.collection("events").doc(eventID).snapshotChanges().pipe(
  mergeMap(document => {
    // This is a promise the below part 
    return EventImporterJSON.getFromJSON(document.payload.data())
  })
);
```

However, you can also use `async - await` because operators such as `mergeMap` handle Observables, Promises, arrays, etc. the same way, so you can just return a Promise in `mergeMap`s project function it will work fine.

Typically, you don't need to use multiple `await`s in a single method because the more "Rx" way of doing things is chaining operators, but if you want, you can because the `async` method returns a Promise and RxJS will handle it like any other Promise.

```js
const delayedPromise = () => new Promise(resolve => {
  setTimeout(() => resolve(), 1000);
})

of('a').pipe(
  mergeMap(async v => {
    console.log(1);
    await delayedPromise();
    console.log(2);
    await delayedPromise();
    console.log(3);
    await delayedPromise();
    return v;
  })
).subscribe(console.log);
// 1
// 2
// 3
// a


Live demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-3fujcs
```

Comment: Thanks, as always Martin you give one of the most comprehensive answers. 

I ll mark yours as the accepted but any thoughts for Kevins answer?

Answer (score 9):

Observables can be seen as a layer up to promises, why don't you use your promise this way ?
like this :

```
let getDataFromJson(payloadData){
    return from(EventImporterJSON.getFromJSON(payloadData());
}

return this.afs.collection("events").doc(eventID).snapshotChanges().pipe(
  map(document=>document.payload.data),
  switchMap( payloadData=> getDataFromJson(payloadData)))
.subscribe(result=>{
    //final result
});
```

1 pipe your first observable with map just to simplify your returner value

2 switchMap to another observable which will be your promise as an Observable ( with the "from" operator);

The map operator is made for improve result in synchronous and "pure" way like return only few properties of an object or filter a data, here you want to chain two async operation so I suggest you to keep it in a rx approach

Comment: I like also this answer Kevin